# GTIN Check Digit Validation in Elixir

Tags: elixir

Similar to other [GTIN](https://www.gs1.org/how-calculate-check-digit-manually) validations, the function should take the entire string of the read in barcode, calculate the check digit, and compare it to the check digit on the code. For example, the code `6291041500213` would take the first 12 digits (`629104150021`) and calculate the answer of `3`.

this code should work for GTIN-8, GTIN-12, GTIN-13, GTIN-14, GSIN, SSCC.

I was hoping to get some feedback on the test cases and on the code itself on where it can be DRYed or made more explicit. I realized later on that Elixir now has a built in `mod` fuction which I'll switch to (I read an older Jose article that said it did not)...I think I need to also clean up the areas where it returns `{:ok}` and `{:error}`.

### Code:

```
  @doc """
  Check for valid  GTIN-8, GTIN-12, GTIN-13, GTIN-14, GSIN, SSCC codes

  Returns `{:ok}` or `{:error}`

  ## Examples

      iex> gtin_check_digit("6291041500213")
      {:ok}

      iex> gtin_check_digit("6291041500214")
      {:error}
  """
  @spec gtin_check_digit(string) :: { atom }
  def gtin_check_digit(number) do
    {code, check_digit} = String.split_at(number, String.length(number) - 1)
    calculated_check_digit = code
      |> multiply_and_sum_array
      |> subtract_from_nearest_multiple_of_ten

    case calculated_check_digit == String.to_integer(check_digit) do
      true -> {:ok}
      _ -> {:error}
    end
  end

  @doc """
  Calculates the sum of the digits in a string and multiplied value based on index order

  Returns sum of values

  ## Examples

      iex> multiply_and_sum_array("629104150021")
      57

  """
  @spec multiply_and_sum_array(string) :: number
  def multiply_and_sum_array(number) do
    number
      |> String.codepoints
      |> Enum.map(fn(x) -> String.to_integer(x) end)
      |> Enum.reverse
      |> Stream.with_index
      |> Enum.reduce(0, fn({num, idx}, acc) ->
        acc + (num * mult_by_index_code(idx))
      end)
  end


  @doc """
  Calculates the difference of the highest rounded multiple of 10

  Returns the difference of the highest rounded multiple of 10

  ## Examples

      iex> subtract_from_nearest_multiple_of_ten(57)
      3

  """
  @spec subtract_from_nearest_multiple_of_ten(number) :: number
  def subtract_from_nearest_multiple_of_ten(number) do
    mod(10 - mod(number, 10), 10)
  end

  #def mult_by_index_code(index) when mod(index, 2) == 0, do: 3 #these did not work because I cannot call mod within the `when`
  #def mult_by_index_code(index), do: 1
  def mult_by_index_code(index) do
    case mod(index, 2) do
      0 -> 3
      _ -> 1
    end
  end

  defp mod(x,y) when x > 0, do: rem(x, y);
  defp mod(x,y) when x < 0, do: rem(y+x, y);
  defp mod(0,_y), do: 0
```

### Tests

```
 test "gtin_check_digit function with valid number" do
    number = "6291041500213"
    assert {:ok} == gtin_check_digit(number)
  end

  test "gtin_check_digit function with invalid number" do
    number = "6291041500214"
    assert {:error} == gtin_check_digit(number)
    assert {:error} == gtin_check_digit("6291041533213")
  end

  test "mult_by_index_code function" do
    assert mult_by_index_code(1) == 1
    assert mult_by_index_code(2) == 3
    assert mult_by_index_code(3) == 1
    assert mult_by_index_code(4) == 3
  end

  test "multiply_and_sum_array function" do
    number = "629104150021"
    #number = [6,2,9,1,0,4,1,5,0,0,2,1]
    assert 57 == multiply_and_sum_array(number)
  end

  test "subtract_from_nearest_multiple_of_ten function" do
    assert 3 == subtract_from_nearest_multiple_of_ten(57)
  end
```

As I refine this, I'll create a hex package to use a common utility library for the elixir community.